# Callibration of Intel RealSense Camera

Tags: camera-calibration, realsense, realsense-camera

I am using a 640x480 pixel image feed to detect objects using YOLOv5. Should it be necessary to change the calibration of Intel RealSense as well since my requirement is 640x480 pixel resolution?

Below are the camera calibration parameters:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! The default parameters work pretty well. So there is no need to touch them in general.

Comment: You mean rectified resolution need not be changed?